# Append Item to Linked List

Tags: c++, loops, linked-list, append, nodes

So I am completely and utterly confused on how to append a node to my linked list.  Basically, I have an Inventory object (linked list), comprised of nodes containing an ItemStack object.  This ItemStack object contains the name of an item and the quantity of that item.  Within my Inventory.cpp file I have a function named addItems() that has an ItemStack parameter.

For some reason when I attempt to append an ItemStack node to the end of my list and output the results the only output is the first and last ItemStack. It skips over the ItemStack nodes in the middle.  I am not sure if they are just being overwritten or what is going on.  I know it has to do with either my Inventory.cpp file or my Inventory.h file, as I am not allowed to modify any other file.

The input for this program is read from two files.  itemList-01.txt  and inventoryList-01.txt.  Furthermore,  the number of occupied slots in an inventory are not being being updated. If anyone would care to shed some light on the issues I am having I would greatly appreciate it.  I have been at it for days with no progress.  I AM ATTACHING A LINK TO ALL OF MY CODE IF THE BELOW CODE IS NOT HELPFUL ENOUGH.(REMEMBER ONLY INVENTORY.CPP and INVENTORY.H CAN BE MODIFIED).  Thanks in advance.

https://github.com/brussell757/CS330/tree/master/Assignment_1

START OF INVENTORY.H FILE

```
   #ifndef INVENTORY_H_INCLUDED
   #define INVENTORY_H_INCLUDED

   #include <iostream>

   #include "ItemStack.h"

   /**
   * An Inventory is composed of n slots. Each slot may store only
   * one type of item--specified by *slots*. 
   * <p>
   * Once all slots are filled, no additional Item types may be
   * stored. Individual slots may contain any number of the same 
   * Item.
   */
    class Inventory{
    private:
    /**
     * Each Node represents one Inventory slot--i.e., space
     */
    struct Node{
        ItemStack data; ///< One ItemStack
        Node *next;     ///< Next ItemStack Node

        /**
         * Create an empty *Air* Node
         */
        Node();

        /**
         * Create a Node that contains an ItemStack, *s*
         */
        Node( ItemStack s );
    };

    Node *first;  ///< First inventory slot
    Node *last;   ///< Last inventory slot

    int slots;    ///< Capacity
    int occupied; ///< Number of occupied slots

    /**
     * Disassembles the list for Deconstructor
     */
    void disassemble();

    public:
    /**
     * Default to 10 slots
     */
    Inventory();

    /**
     * Create an inventory with n slots
     *
     * @pre n > 0
     */
    Inventory( int n );

    /**
     * Copy an already existing Inventory
     */
    Inventory( const Inventory &src );

    /**
     * Destruct an Inventory
     */
    ~Inventory();

    /**
     * Add one or more items to the inventory list
     *
     * @return true if *stack* was added and false otherwise
     */
    bool addItems( ItemStack stack );

    /**
     * Print a Summary of the Inventory and all Items contained within
     */
    void display( std::ostream &outs ) const;

    /**
     *
     */
    Inventory::Node* begin() const;

    /**
     *
     */
    Inventory::Node* end() const;

    /**
     * Overloaded assignment operator for Inventory
     */
    Inventory& operator=( const Inventory &rhs );
    };

   /**
   * Print the Inventory through use of the display member function
   */
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &outs, const Inventory &prt)    {
   prt.display( outs );
   return outs;
}

   #endif
```

START OF INVENTORY.CPP FILE

```
    /**
    * Used to add items to the Inventory
    */
    bool Inventory::addItems ( ItemStack stack ){

    Node* new_node = nullptr;

    // Sets new_node equal to a new node containing the current ItemStack
    new_node = new Node(stack);

    // Insert ItemStack into empty Inventory
    if(this->first == nullptr) {

        // Sets the first node in the Inventory to the new Node
        this->first = new_node;

        // Sets the last node in the Inventory to the new Node
        this->last = new_node;

        // Increase the number of occupied slots by 1
        occupied++;

        return true;

    } else {

        // Statement that executes if the maximum number of slots in the Inventory have not been filled
        if(occupied <= slots) {

            // Sets current node to the head
            Node *curr = this->first; 

            // Sets trail node to nullptr
            Node *trail = nullptr;

            // Traverse the list
            while(curr != nullptr) { 

                // Sets the (first->next) node to the new_node (new ItemStack)
                curr->next = new_node; 

                // Sets the trail node to the current node (first)
                trail = curr;

                // Sets the current node to the node after new_node (nullptr)
                curr = new_node->next;

                return true;

            }

            // Increase the number of occupied slots by 1
            occupied++;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use paragraphs please. Relevant code must be included in the question.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that

Comment: Please post your `Inventory` class definition.  Also, why is your loop to add to the end of the list doing all sorts of things in the loop?  Aren't you simply supposed to traverse to the end of the list first, and then when you get there, you add the node?

Comment: I tired that but for some reason I get a segmentation fault error when doing so

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're supposed to traverse the list until you get to the end.  Once you get to the end of the list, *then* you add the node.

Not tested, but this is what you more than likely should have done:

```
    Node *curr = this->first; 
    Node *temp = curr; 
    while(curr != nullptr) 
    { 
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    temp->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = nullptr;
    last = new_node;
```

This simply traverses the list until it gets to the end.  A temporary keeps track of the last node.  Then once this is done, you just point the last valid node to the new node.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the advice I will try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: @Brandon  Then your linked list class is broken before you even get to this code.  There is nothing in the code I posted that should cause an infinite loop.  If it is an issue to merely loop until you get to the end, then there are bigger things wrong with your code that you need to look for.

Comment: @Brandon I looked at your other code.  Your copy constructor for `Inventory` is broken.  So the requirement that you can't change any other code cannot be fulfilled if you want your `addItems` to work.  I noticed this right away when your tests included a `vector<Inventory>`, and the only way that will work is if `Inventory` is safely copyable and assignable, and unfortunately, it isn't.  Your copy constructor creates fake copies, and doing so causes undefined, if not undesirable behavior.

Comment: You also have a broken `parseInventoryFile` function.  There is no reason for this function to be using `new Inventory` anywhere.

Comment: Not allowed to manipulate that code. Only allowed to touch Inventory.h and Inventory.cpp.  I finally got it working. Main reason I was having so much trouble was because I set occupied equal to src.occupied in my copy constructor when it should have been set to 0. My updated code on github is the working code if you want to take a look at it.